# How is as.numeric used here?

Tags: r, piecewise

I've been trying to figure out how to mimic a piecewise linear regression model developed in the pricing software Emblem, using R.  I did that using @Roland's answer in the below post.

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/61805/standard-error-of-slopes-in-piecewise-linear-regression-with-known-breakpoints

So to get the slopes, thanks to @Roland, I used the as.numeric((variable < X)) to get the slope of the second segment in the predictor variables.

What is going on here?  Why does the "as.numeric" give me the correct answer?  I can't find documentation on it and I would like to understand why this works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It converts a boolean (`TRUE` / `FALSE`) value to numeric (`1` / `0`).

(The R-y name for boolean is "logical": `is.logical(TRUE)` returns `TRUE`.)

`x < 10 # TRUE if x is less than 10, FALSE if x is 10 or more`

`as.numeric(x<10)  # 1 if x is less than 10, 0 if x is 10 or more`

This being said, you don't really need an `as.numeric` there. What you could do instead is:

```
# will also work:
mod2 <- lm(y~I((x<9.6)*x)+(x<9.6)+I((x>=9.6)*x)+(x>=9.6)-1)
```

This version will use the boolean values directly -- these are converted implicitly to factors, and how a factor functions within `lm` is that it is converted into `k-1` dichotomous variables where `k` is the number of levels. So that's why, if you use the code above, you'll see variable names like `x < 9.6TRUE` in the `lm` output.

Then again, technically, `as.numeric` is a hack, and a more transparent way to do it may be something like `ifelse(x<9.6,1,0)`. But hacks are not necessarily bad, so you might also prefer a hackier hack such as  `(x<9.6)*1` but that won't work within a formula because `*` has a special meaning in formulas, so you'd have to use `I` around it:  `I((x<9.6)*1)` - I'd say `as.numeric` looks cleaner.

Comment: Makes sense now. Thanks.